# How to disable new row when Google Form collects responses for Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-query

When Google Forms collects responses, it creates an entirely new row in the Google Sheet which I don't want to happen because I am using a `VLOOKUP` for another sheet and it's not grabbing the data I want. Ideally, when a response is collected, I don't want it to create a new row but to be in the same row I have created so the `vlookup` function would work. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here - is there an example sheet you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

You can (should) use **`QUERY`** formula to recollect all your data in your desired format/output and then mine this created **`QUERY`** with your **`VLOOKUP`** formula. Syntax example:

```
=QUERY(FormResponses1!A:Z; "select * where A is not null"; 0)
```